# Can a storm topology be deactivated and reactivated by a spout or a bolt?

Tags: java, apache-storm

When certain conditions are met, like encountering a special type of tuple, I want to deactivate the topology . Is this can be done in spout/bolt ?
And if yes, is there any way to reactivate the topology from spout/bolt too ?

Comment: `activate` and `deactivate` are just methods like `ack` or `nextTuple` in `ISpout` interface. Though I haven't deactivate/reactivate in a spout before, I guess it is possible.

Comment: Interesting question, this would be useful for maintenance..

Comment: @halfelf activate and deactivate are nice plug ins, on which further implementation strategies can be made. But, i still think activating after deactivating will be quite hard, as reactivating strategy will be required to run even after the spout is deactivated.

Answer (score 2):

I have added all three actions in bolow code to activate/deactivate/kill. This can be called from independent java code (outside spout/bolt).

Deactivate from spout or bolt is straight forward but reactivating would be tricky as your spout/bolt is not actively running java program once deactivated.

```
import backtype.storm.generated.KillOptions;
import backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus.Client;
import backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;

Client client = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(Utils.readStormConfig()).getClient();

client.activate(topologyName);
client.deactivate(topologyName);

KillOptions killOpts = new KillOptions();
killOpts.set_wait_secs(30);
client.killTopologyWithOpts(topologyName, killOpts);
```